# How to store images in node.js with mongoDB efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongodb

js with mongoDB now will it be better to store pics in mongoDB or should i store them in a File System i am building an android app like Zomato now can anyone please tell me in detail which will be better and where.

Comment: each approach has it's upsides and downsides, you'd need to specify what exactly would make one better than the other for this to not be too opinionated.

Comment: i mean in terms of performance when i will load them on app then where will it be faster.

Comment: File system will almost always be faster because even with mongodb, a trip to the file system is required.

Answer (score -2):

The best practice is to let your mongo keep only a reference to file and have the file located on file system. Mongo is not designed to save binary data and large data. Mongo is document store where you want to save hierarchic data.

Comment: can u pls tell me how to store a image and send it when a request comes. Is there any good npm library for that.